# Sumar datos iguales en DataTable y pasarlos a una nueva DataTable C#

Tags: c#, datatables

Tengo un `query` `SELECT` cualquiera:

```
SELECT*FROM XXXX
```

lo que recupero lo guardo en una `DataTable`, digamos que esa `DataTable` se ve asi (el reflejo de la tabla):

```
codigo--------descripcion--------total
0001          papaya             100,5
0002          mango                 50
0001          papaya             200,5
```

Como puedo hacer para recorrer la `DataTable` o algun metodo similar que busque si existe algo con similar codigo y lo sume y pasarlo a nueva DataTable con los datos asi:

```
codigo--------descripcion--------total
0001          papaya               301
0002          mango                 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ayudarte con linq, usando un `group by`

```
var query = from row in dt1.AsEnumerable()
               group row by row.Field<string>("codigo") into g
               select new {
                   codigo = g.Key,
                   descripcion = g.First().Field<string>("descripcion"),
                   total = g.Sum(x=> x.Field<int>("total"))
                };
```

[Crear un objeto DataTable a partir de una consulta (LINQ to DataSet)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset)

para obtener el `datatable` de respuesta usarias

```
DataTable dtResult = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: consulta rapida, si tengo 2 DataTables que tienen las misma columnas (pero diferentes datos)y quiero unirlas en una sola DataTable, usaria `.merge()`?

Comment: si puedes usar el merge del datatable y despeus con linq los agrupas para sumar el total

Comment: perdona la molestia otra vez, pero por que me marca error en `descripcion = g.First().descripcion,` mas que todo en `.descripcion`?

Comment: olvide que era un row del datatable y no se accede directo, sino usando `g.First().Field<string>("descripcion")`

Comment: Gracias pero no me deja usar `CopyToDataTable`

Comment: si revisas la documentacion del link veras que ese metodo es una extension que esta en `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` valida que tengas la referencia y ademas el using